# how to solve a second order nonlinear differential equation in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, ode, solution

I have a equation in the form : (M*X") +( K1*X)+(K2*X^2)=0
Now I want to solve this equation with Matlab. I would appreciate if someone could share a link which contains the analytical solution for such a equation.
Thank you :)

Comment: Is `X"` a second order derivative? If so, how `X` looks like?

Comment: Do you want matlab or a manual solution? Did you at least try to use the symbolic solver and the numerical ODE solvers and if yes, please report on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a symbolic solution, you can use the following code:

```
syms k1 k2 x m;
f = (m * diff(x,2)) + (k1 * x) + (k2 * x^2) == 0;

a = solve(f)
```

Comment: I want the response in time domain. By your solution we just get the answers "0" and "K1/K2".